# Replace string in between round brackets

Tags: python, regex, bash, perl, shell

I have an expression that looks like this:

```
when v(a.b.c.d.e.f.g) = v(m.n.o.x.y.z)
```

I need the final output to be:

```
when v(a.b^c^d^e^f:g) = v(m.n^o^x^y:z)
```

Simply put, how can i replace each "`.`" by "`^`" starting from the second occurrence of "`.`" in each expression between `v();` while replacing the last "`.`" with "`:`" in each expression between `v()` ? Both `v()` expressions appear on the same line.

I tried the following :

```
setenv test "when v(a.b.c.d.e.f.g) = v(m.n.o.x.y.z)"

echo $test | awk -F"(" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\)/){sub(").*","",$i)};print $i}}' | \
    sed -E 's/\./\^/g2' | sed 's/\(.*\)\^/\1\:/'
```

This gives the following:

```
a.b^c^d^e^f:g
m.n^o^x^y:z
```

I need to know how after that I can replace the original statement with the modified text above so that if finally will look like this :

```
when v(a.b^c^d^e^f:g) = v(m.n^o^x^y:z)
```

I tried the following

```
$ENV{"str"} = "when v(a.b.c.d.e.f.g) = v(m.n.o.x.y.z)";

$str =~ s{(\w(\w\.)(.*?)\.(\w))}{
    my ( $first, $temp, $last) = ( $1, $2, $3 );
    $temp =~ s/\./^/g;
    $first . $temp . ':' . $last
}ge;

system( 'echo $str' );
```

but it did not work =(

Any ideas ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the issue you're having with the code you've written.

Comment: In Perl you can try for example: `$str =~ s{(\w\(\w\.)(.*?)\.(\w\))}{ my ( $first, $temp, $last) = ( $1, $2, $3); $temp =~ s/\./^/g; $first . $temp . ':' . $last}ge`

Comment: I tried the following :    $ENV{"str"} = "when v(a.b.c.d.e.f.g) = v(m.n.o.x.y.z)"; 
$str =~ s{(\w\(\w\.)(.*?)\.(\w\))}{ my ( $first, $temp, $last) = ( $1, $2, $3); $temp =~ s/\./^/g; $first . $temp . ':' . $last}ge;
system('echo $str');    but did not work =(

Comment: @SarahMohamed You have to first declare and define the string, then you must print it. No need to use `echo` from within Perl. If the string should be in an environment variable, as you indicate, you will have to modify that variable and not `$str` or alternatively, copy the environment variable to `$str` first. You also forgot some of the backslashes in the regex

Comment: @HåkonHægland The string should not be in an environment variable, rather in a file. I am new with perl, can you help explain what i should do so that this works by providing the file including the string ?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you said that the string should be in a file.
Here is an example, illustrating that case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = 'test.txt';

open ( my $fh, '<', $file_name ) or die "Could not open file '$file_name': $!";

my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

$str =~ s{(\w\(\w+\.)(.*?)\.(\w+\))}{
  my ( $first, $temp, $last) = ( $1, $2, $3);
  $temp =~ s/\./^/g;
  $first . $temp . ':' . $last}ge;

print $str;
```

First we read the content of the file `test.txt` into the string `$str`. Then we do the replacements. And finally print the result.

Comment: Assume test.txt includes the following lines : \n                

.meas tran trst_write_1a_0000 when v(xsram.xcore_0right_b0.xcore_d0_bl0_3_wl0_3.xcore_bl0_1_wl0_1.mn11.g) ='0.2*supply_mem' td='4*tp' rise=1  \n                

.meas tran trst_write_1b_0000 when v(xsram.xgio0_right.xgio_bit2.xldp.xprech_wd.m0_1_1.d) ='v(xsram.xgio0_right.xgio_bit2.xldp.xprech_wd.m1_1_1.d)-0.010' td='trst_write_1a_0000' rise=1   \n                    

When i use your suggested perl script, no replacements are made and the printed lines are exactly the same as the input file.

Comment: Hi Sarah. Yes but now the parameters to `v` contains more than a single letter as it did in your original question. For example `v(xsram..` here `xsram` is five letters not a single letter as in your original example

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle your new specifications. We now use `\w+` instead of just `\w` in the regex